# Пишу бота на python. Нужна помощь с БД

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Вот код

```
import sqlite3
class dbworker:
    def __init__(self,database_file):
    self.connection = sqlite3.connect(database_file)
    self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    def user_exists(self, user_id):
    #Проверка есть ли юзер в бд
    with self.connection:
        result = self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `telegram_id` = ?', (user_id,)).fetchall()
        return bool(len(result))
    def add_user(self,telegram_username,telegram_id,full_name):
    #Добавляем нового юзера
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`telegram_username`, `telegram_id`,`full_name`) VALUES(?,?,?)", (telegram_username,telegram_id,full_name))
    def create_profile(self,telegram_id,telegram_username,name,description,city,photo,sex,age,social_link):
    #Создаём анкету
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `profile_list` (`telegram_id`,`telegram_username`,`name`,`description`,`city`,`photo`,`sex`,`age`,`social_link`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (telegram_id,telegram_username,name,description,city,photo,sex,age,social_link))
def profile_exists(self,user_id):
    #Проверка есть ли анкета в бд
    with self.connection:
        result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `profile_list` WHERE `telegram_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
        return bool(len(result))
def delete_profile(self,user_id):
    #Удаление анкеты
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM `profile_list` WHERE `telegram_id` = ?",(user_id,))
def all_profile(self,user_id):
    #поиск по анкетам
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `profile_list` WHERE `telegram_id` = ?",(user_id,)).fetchall()
def edit_description(self,description,user_id):
    #изменение описания
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute('UPDATE `profile_list` SET `description` = ? WHERE `telegram_id` = ?',(description,user_id))
def edit_age(self,age,user_id):
    #изменение возвраста
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute('UPDATE `profile_list` SET `age` = ? WHERE `telegram_id` = ?',(age,user_id))
def search_profile(self,city,age,sex):
    #поиск хаты
    try:
        if str(sex) == 'мужчина':
            sex_search = 'женщина'
        else:
            sex_search = 'мужчина'
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("SELECT `telegram_id` FROM `profile_list` WHERE `city` = ? AND `sex` = ? AND `age` BETWEEN ? and 54",(city,sex_search,age)).fetchall()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
def get_info(self,user_id):
    #получение ифнормации по профилю
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `profile_list` WHERE `telegram_id` = ?",(user_id,)).fetchone()
def search_profile_status(self,user_id):
    #возвращение статуса
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("SELECT `search_id` FROM `users` WHERE `telegram_id` = ?",(user_id,)).fetchone()
def edit_profile_status(self,user_id,num):
    #изменение статуса
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute('UPDATE `users` SET `search_id` = ? WHERE `telegram_id` = ?',(str(num + 1),user_id))
def edit_zero_profile_status(self,user_id):
    #изменение статуса на 0 когда анкеты заканчиваются
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute('UPDATE `users` SET `search_id` = 0 WHERE `telegram_id` = ?',(user_id,))
def set_city_search(self,city,user_id):
    #задования города для поиска
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute('UPDATE `users` SET `city_search` = ? WHERE `telegram_id` = ?',(city,user_id))
def get_info_user(self,user_id):
    #получение информации по юзеру
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `telegram_id` = ?",(user_id,)).fetchone()
def check_rating(self,user_id):
    #чек по рейтингу
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("SELECT `rating` FROM `profile_list` WHERE `telegram_id` = ?",(user_id,)).fetchone()
def up_rating(self,count,user_id):
    #добавление по рейтингу
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute('UPDATE `profile_list` SET `rating` = ? WHERE `telegram_id` = ?',(count + 1,user_id))
def top_rating(self):
    #вывод топа по рейтингу
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute('SELECT `telegram_id` FROM `profile_list` ORDER BY `rating` DESC LIMIT 5').fetchall()
def count_user(self):
    #вывод кол-ва юзеров
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`').fetchone()
```

выдает ошибку:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: profile_list

Comment: А на какой строчке происходит ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Это означает, что у тебя не создана таблица `profile_list`. Создайте её таким образом:

```
CREATE TABLE profile_list
(
    Id INT,
   # Добавляйте нужные колонки
)
```

Или вот так (хотя это одно и тоже):

```
self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE profile_list (Id INT, ...)")
```

Comment: Теперь выдает другую ошибку: sqlite3.OperationalError: table profile_list already exists

Comment: Значит, что она уже существует. Не подскажите, на какой строчке происходит ошибка?

Comment: result = self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `telegram_id` = ?', (user_id,)).fetchall() 
В этой строчке

Comment: Нужно указывать через `%s`, а не знак вопроса

Comment: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: telegram_id 
Теперь вот такая ошибка

Comment: Покажи мне всю таблицу

Comment: Так она же пустая

Comment: Мне не нужны данные. Колонки покажи